# Using a Timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to make a form invisible for x amount of time in c#.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 16, accepted):

BFree has posted similar code in the time it took me to test this, but here's my attempt:

```
this.Hide();
var t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
{
    Interval = 3000 // however long you want to hide for
};
t.Tick += (x, y) => { t.Enabled = false; this.Show(); };
t.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Cleaner approach than mine. +1

Comment: Timers implement IDisposable, you should be calling it.

Comment: I suppose you could call Dispose() manually from within the event handler, but you couldn't wrap it in a using() block or the timer would be disposed before it got a chance to fire, three seconds later.

Answer (score 8):

Quick and dirty solution taking advantage of closures. No `Timer` required!

```
private void Invisibilize(TimeSpan Duration)
    {
        (new System.Threading.Thread(() => { 
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Hide));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Duration); 
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Show)); 
            })).Start();
    }
```

Example:

```
// Makes form invisible for 5 seconds.

Invisibilize(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
```

Answer (score 3):

At the class level do something like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
private int counter = 0;
```

In the constructor do this:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        }
```

Then your event handler:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter == 5) //or whatever amount of time you want it to be invisible
            {
                this.Visible = true;
                timer.Stop();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
```

Then wherever you want to make it invisible (I'll demonstrate here on a button click):

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            timer.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind there are several types of timers available:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

And don't forget to disable the timer for the duration of the handler, lest you interrupt your self.  Rather embarrassing.